# ILMerge outputs assembly with processorArchitecture=x86

Tags: c#, .net, assembly, ilmerge

I have an issue with ILMerge, latest release 2.12.0803. Even my assemblies have processor architecture set to MSIL, the output merged assembly has x86.

The way I run ILMerge is:

```
ILMerge.exe /t:library /targetPlatform="v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /keyfile:key.snk /output:"Test.dll" a.dll b.dll ... other assemblies
```

On build time I have a warning:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "Test", "x86"

and at run-time I get a File Not found Exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Test, Version=3.9.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fd4d0b13dde34b0' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Running gacutil:

> C:\Windows\system32>gacutil /l "Test, Version=3.9.32.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fd4d0b13dde34b0" Microsoft (R) .NET
>   Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.17929 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:   Test,
>   Version=3.9.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok en=8fd4d0b13dde34b0,
>   processorArchitecture=x86

Is there a way to change the processorArchitecture to MSIL for the merged assembly?

Comment: MSIL isn't a processor architecture, is it?

Comment: this is what gacutil outputs:The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies: Test, Version=3.9.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fd4d0b13dde34b0, processorArchitecture=MSIL. So, is it?..I was clearly referring to the parameter name..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was that one of the assemblies requires 32 bits, see ServiceStack.Redis.

From ILMerge log file:

Checking to see that all of the input assemblies have a compatible PeKind.

```
ServiceStack.PeKind = ILonly
ServiceStack.Interfaces.PeKind = ILonly
ServiceStack.Common.PeKind = ILonly
ServiceStack.OrmLite.PeKind = ILonly
ServiceStack.Redis.PeKind = ILonly, Requires32bits
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.PeKind = ILonly
ServiceStack.Text.PeKind = ILonly
log4net.PeKind = ILonly
```